# Python EXE (pyinstaller) and reloading directory of dynamic imports

Tags: python, import, reload, pyinstaller

I've created a wxPython (not sure if it's relevant) executable with pyinstaller that has a particular task of loading and executing python scripts from a directory that gets added using `sys.path.append` within the code. During execution, the application can see and import the contents of the directory just fine. If a file is added to this directory, however, the app will attempt to import it and fail saying there's no module by that name. The app has to be restarted to load the new module. The files are being imported dynamically using the `import` statement.

Is there any way to get around this? The import works just fine if the application is not compiled.